# Prove or disprove: The solution set of a system of 10 linear equations in 12 variables can be a line in $\mathbb{R}^{12}$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, proof-writing

Prove or disprove: The solution set of a system of 10 linear equations in 12 variables can be a line in $\mathbb{R}^{12}$.

I believe this statement is false, but I am not sure how to disprove it.

Any help is appreciated, thanks.

Comment: rank-nullity formula?

Comment: What have you tried so far? How can you apply what you're currently learning about to the problem?

Answer (score 1):

Let $A \in \mathbb R^{10 \times 12}$ and $b \in \mathbb R^{10}.$ Then consider the mapping $f(x):=Ax$ and the system

$$ (*) \quad f(x)=b.$$

Suppose that the set of solutions $S$  of $(*)$ is a line. Then there is a special solution $x_0$ of $(*)$ and a solution $p \ne 0$ of $f(x)=0$ such that

$$S=\{x_0+tp: t \in \mathbb R\}.$$

This means that $ker(A)= span \{p\},$ hence $ \dim ker(A)=1.$ By the rank-nullity theorem, we have

$$12= rank(A)+1,$$

hence $rank(A)=11$, a contradiction, since $rank(A) \le 10.$